# Cythonized package cannot be installed due to incompatible platform

Tags: pip, cython

I have built a cythonized package on Ubuntu 20.04.

The Python version I used to build is 3.7.1, and cython is of version 0.29.30.

The generated package is with name `bbbox-2.0.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl`. I manage to install this package on other servers with Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

However when I tried installing the same package on `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)`, I got the following error

```
using pip 22.2 from /venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Non-user install because user site-packages disabled
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-tu_4hz24
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-build-tracker-q85jg79w
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-build-tracker-q85jg79w
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-build-tracker-q85jg79w
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-build-tracker-q85jg79w
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-7_4efkhe
ERROR:bbbox-2.0.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 370, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 73, in resolve
    collected = self.factory.collect_root_requirements(root_reqs)
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 493, in collect_root_requirements
    requested_extras=(),
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 452, in _make_requirement_from_install_req
    self._fail_if_link_is_unsupported_wheel(ireq.link)
  File "/venvs/dztradeio_pre/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 138, in _fail_if_link_is_unsupported_wheel
    raise UnsupportedWheel(msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel:bbbox-2.0.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Remote version of pip: 22.2
Local version of pip:  22.2
Was pip installed by pip? True
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-build-tracker-q85jg79w'
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manylinux standard is not compatible.
On Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), the highest compatible manylinux standard is manylinux_2_24, while your package is of manylinux_2_31.

You could use the following command to check the compatible manylinux standards on your target machine.

```
python -m pip debug --verbose
```

To build a package which is compatible of manylinux 2_24, You could use a docker image from  https://github.com/pypa/manylinux.